# C# XNA 4.0 Exception: "Cannot Open File"

Tags: c#, image, xna

I am working in XNA 4.0 Game Studio (C#), and I am trying to load an image using the LoadContent() method. I have loaded numerous image files into this game and they all work 100% fine, but for some reason, XNA will not open files inside one of my loadContent methods. Here is the method:

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        //spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        //Sets up an array of textures to be used in the Icon class
        Texture2D[] icons = new Texture2D[24];

        #region Loading talent textures
        //These are all of the icons that need to be loaded for the talents
        //Paladin
        icons[0] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\Dropbox\Public\platformer\Platformer\Content\Talents\blade_of_light3.jpg");
        icons[1] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Talents\\divine_grace");
        icons[2] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Talents\\divine_storm");
        icons[3] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Talents\\hammer_of_the_righteous");
        icons[4] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Talents\\healing_hands");
        icons[5] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Talents\\heavenly_fury");
        icons[6] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Talents/momentum_of_light");
        icons[7] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Talents/retribution");
        icons[8] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Talents/righteous_fury");
        icons[9] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Talents/sanctuary");
        icons[10] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Talent/searing_light");
        icons[11] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Talent/wrath_of_the_heavens");

        //Warrior
        icons[12] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\bloodstorm");
        icons[13] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\bloodthirst");
        icons[14] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\die_by_the_sword");
        icons[15] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\furious_blades");
        icons[16] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\unleash_rage");
        icons[17] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\lifeblood");
        icons[18] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\red_like_my_rage");
        icons[19] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\eternal_thirst");
        icons[20] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\bladesurge");
        icons[21] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\bathed_in_blood");
        icons[22] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\bladerunner");
        icons[23] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\bloodfury");
        icons[24] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Talents\grapple_chain");
        #endregion
```

As you can see, I have tried using the ENTIRE file location. It finds the file, but throws an exception when the LoadContent() method is called and says "Cannot open file blade_of_light3."

I do not get any errors about escape paths or anything like that, and I have used this sort of file path for other images, and they work fine. It's just here, in this class, in this loadContent method, that they won't work.

Answer (score 5):

The Content.Load methods does not load files, it loads specialized content or assets. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197848.aspx).
You can't load files directly, you can only load assets. These assets are generated via the [content pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447745.aspx).
This is mainly to provide an abstract layer for content. Because XNA is platform independent, and on one machine you may be use a bigger image or different image, you only need to change the asset in the pipeline and can reuse the code.

Comment: I've loaded the image files into the solution explorer. The files are inside of the project. I do this with all of the art files, like the backgrounds and sounds and whatnot, and they ALL work fine. It's just this method that won't work for some reason that I can't see.

Comment: But, according to the first link, it is capable of loading those assets as files. Note the example loading a model.

Comment: @pickypg Also note the missing extension. The file was added as an asset. The content pipeline will generate a name relative to the path in the content pipeline project.

Comment: @Henry check the documentation on the first link. It says **Before a ContentManager can load an asset, you need to add the asset to your game project using the steps described in How to: Add Game Assets to a Content Project.** Which does not mean you should add the files to your project, but to the content pipeline project.

Comment: +1 @dowhilefor Good point. The [How to: Add Game Assets to a Content Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb313966.aspx) should have been a link on that page rather than bolded text. Would have prevented my stupid comment :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to [dowhilefor's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586810/c-xna-4-0-exception-cannot-open-file/6586861#6586861), if you want to load a raw `.jpg` file (or `.png`), you can do so like this:

```
using(var s = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
    Texture2D texture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, s);
}
```

*Unlike* when you load something using `ContentManager`, *you* "own" it in this case. This means you are responsible for calling `Dispose()` on it in `UnloadContent`.

Also *unlike* when you go through the content pipeline (using the default settings), the texture that you load will not have premultiplied-alpha. You need to apply premultiplication yourself, or render it with `BlendState.NonPremultiplied`.

Of course, unless you are unable to for some reason (eg: you're downloading images from the internet, or you're letting your end user pick them), **you should use the content pipeline**.

Comment: One problem with the content pipeline is that its very slow. Loading from a file and then premultipling the alpha yourself is 2 to 3 times faster.

Comment: @ClassicThunder Do you have something to back up that claim? The content-pipeline does all of the decoding and  processing at *build-time*, so at *run-time* it's going to be a *lot* faster than decoding a texture and then doing premultiplication on it.

Comment: For the Windows Phone I do and for the PC (which I didn't think of) it is only slightly slower. http://jakepoz.com/jake_poznanski__speeding_up_xna.html

Comment: @ClassicThunder that's fascinating! I wonder what the cause is? I'd guess that the smaller file is faster to retrieve from flash. I'd be interested to try it on PC. I'm not sure I like your premultiplication code (`file` is not disposed, and perhaps handling `ContentLost`?) - I wonder if premultiplied PNGs might be better and faster still?